# How to display custom taxonomy fields into category loop?

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-fields, advanced-custom-fields

I have that code in my category.php which enables list subcategories

```
<?php $categories = get_categories(array('child_of' => 7)); ?>
<?php foreach ($categories as $child) { ?>
//do stuff
<?php } ?>
```

For categories I've created custom text field with name = text. And now I want to show that custom field inside this loop. Can you help me please? I've tryed

```
<?php $categories = get_categories(array('child_of' => 3)); ?>
<?php foreach ($categories as $child) { ?>
<h2><?php echo $child->cat_name; ?></h2>
<p> <?php echo $child->category_description; ?> </p>
<p><?php echo get_field( 'text', $term->taxonomy . '_' . $term->term_id ); ?></p>
<?php } ?>
```

This code show Cat name, cat description but no custom field.. Help me please to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php $categories = get_categories(array('child_of' => 3)); ?>
<?php foreach ($categories as $child) { ?>
<h2><?php echo $child->cat_name; ?></h2>
<p> <?php echo $child->category_description; ?> </p>
<p><?php echo get_field( 'text', $child->taxonomy . '_' . $child->term_id ); ?>           </p>
<?php } ?>
```

You used *$term* instead od *$child*